# Need to reformat a Windows Boot Drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

Recently I've made a computer from scratch, and in doing so made a flash drive into a windows boot drive. Now, I can't reformat it, and I would rather like to have it back. When I try to do anything with it I get an I/O error, and I can't do anything with it. I really need some help. Thanks.

Comment: I need to reformat the flash drive.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried deleting all volumes/partitions from the drive and starting over?

What operating system? If Windows:
You've probably used these tools to set up your computer, but you can also use them to view/delete volumes:

- Disk Management - Run `Diskmgmt.msc` to launch the GUI and see what's on your drive; right click on volumes to see the delete option. [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/overview-of-disk-management).
- DiskPart - Run `DiskPart` from the command line. [Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490893.aspx).

It's possible the flash drive has failed. Can you still boot from it? Have you tried running recovery tools on it? Try one of these:

- Error checking - Right click on the drive, Properties, Tools tab, click Check. For documentation, scroll down to "tools tab" [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2012/05/09/redesigning-chkdsk-and-the-new-ntfs-health-model/).
- Chkdsk - Run `chkdsk /f` followed by the volume letter. [Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491051.aspx).

Update: Downvoter, please express your disagreement in a comment.